# How do I pivot dynamically in Linq using this example

Tags: c#, linq

The problem below is in the code, i.e. the bit that says DY1 =, DY2 =, etc.  I don't know how many there will be so I need to do it dynamically.

Here is my textfile :

```
Product, Origin Year, Development Year, Incremental Value
Comp, 1992, 1992, 110.0
Comp, 1992, 1993, 170.0
Comp, 1993, 1993, 200.0
Non-Comp, 1990, 1990, 45.2
Non-Comp, 1990, 1991, 64.8
Non-Comp, 1990, 1993, 37.0
Non-Comp, 1991, 1991, 50.0
Non-Comp, 1991, 1992, 75.0
Non-Comp, 1991, 1993, 25.0
Non-Comp, 1992, 1992, 55.0
Non-Comp, 1992, 1993, 85.0
Non-Comp, 1993, 1993, 100.0
```

Here is my code (pasted from LinqPad) :

```
void Main()
{
  using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\temp\\ExampleData.txt"))
  {
    var products =
        (from line in reader.Lines()
        where !line.StartsWith("Product")
        let parts = line.Split(',')
        select new {Product=parts[0], Origin_Year=parts[1], Development_Year=parts[2], Incremental_Value=parts[3], DY=int.Parse(parts[2]) - int.Parse(parts[1]) + 1 }).ToList();
    products.Dump();

    var grps = from p in products
    group p by new {p.Product, p.Origin_Year}
    into g
    select (new { g.Key.Product, g.Key.Origin_Year, 

    DY1 = g.Where(c => c.DY == 1).Select (c => c.Incremental_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
    DY2 = g.Where(c => c.DY == 2).Select (c => c.Incremental_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
    DY3 = g.Where(c => c.DY == 3).Select (c => c.Incremental_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
    DY4 = g.Where(c => c.DY == 4).Select (c => c.Incremental_Value).FirstOrDefault()    
    });

    grps.Dump();
  }
}

}// Temporary hack to enable extension methods

/// <summary>
/// Operators for LINQ to Text Files
/// </summary>
public static class Extensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<String> Lines(this TextReader source)
  {
    String line;

    if (source == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    while ((line = source.ReadLine()) != null)
      yield return line;
  }
```

Here is my output :

```
Product   Origin_Year  DY1    DY2    DY3   DY4 
Comp      1992         110.0  170.0  null  null  
Comp      1993         200.0  null   null  null  
Non-Comp  1990         45.2   64.8   null  37.0  
Non-Comp  1991         50.0   75.0   25.0  null  
Non-Comp  1992         55.0   85.0   null  null  
Non-Comp  1993         100.0  null   null  null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best suggestion I can offer is to return an array of values for each possible DY.

Start by modifying `Incremental_Value` field in the `products` query to be a `double` (ie `double.Parse(parts[3])`).

Now create an enumerable for the maximum number of DYs:

```
    var dys = Enumerable.Range(1, products.Max(p => p.DY));
```

Then the `grps` query looks like this:

```
    var grps =
        from p in products
        group p by new
        {
            p.Product,
            p.Origin_Year,
        } into g
        let lookup = g.ToLookup(x => x.DY, x => x.Incremental_Value)
        select new
        {
            g.Key.Product,
            g.Key.Origin_Year, 
            DYs = dys.Select(x => lookup[x].Sum()).ToArray(),
        };
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Your effort gives the same kind of result as I've already come up with, only better, i.e. the DY's sit in their proper places in the arrays which are always the correct length.  I had got as far as a foreach loop to output the results to an SQL table and it occurred to me that a nested foreach loop for each array would solve my problem nicely and it has.  Thank you.